# Vim using the copy command into multiple lines

Tags: vim

There is a vimcast about using copy commands such as `:9copy16`
and its related shorthand `:16t.` Or in rel number mode `:-16t.`
See here: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/long-range-line-duplication/

Anyway i love this command and use it with some frequency, however i often want to use it to insert into multiple places, along the lines of `:-16t-4,-8,+12` with the goal of inserting line -16 to the lines -4,-8, and -12. This however doesn't work.

Is there a builtin way of doing this that anyone is aware of? (I'm frequently remoting and can't use plugins.)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind repeating yourself a little bit, you could do something like:

```
:2t$ | 2t15 | 2t0
```

The problem is that, after each t command, the cursor changes it's position, so you can't use relative positions, unfortunately.